# Update Form React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I recently read online that it is not a good practice to copy your props to state as we will have 2 different "source of truth".
Suppose I have data like :

```
{
   "name" : "Some name",
   "projectName" : "React redux project",
   "description" : "Some description",
   "userList" : ["user1", "user1"]
}
```

This data is stored in my redux store.

Now I want to have a form where user can update the values, and when they click on the update button only then my store gets updated. To achieve this, I have to copy the props coming from store to my state, handle all the changes by updating the state, and then dispatch action whenever user clicks the button.

Is there any other way to achieve this without copying the props to state ? I don't want to use any extra library and use only react-redux.

Comment: That's exactly what you need to do. Copy your redux state into your form state ( local state ) only when the user updates the form, update your redux state as well.

Comment: It's not considered a copy. You have the original value that's used for the initial form value and when the user changes the form it'll change that value but not the original so 2 seperate values having 2 distinct uses.